# Redundancy requests with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to build in redundancy into my app where if a server is down it will try a backup redundancy server upon failure of the first request.

Aside from doing

```
Call<LoginResult> loginCall = apiInterface.login(....);
loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            //do normal stuff
        }else{
            //try second url
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable t) {
        //Try second url
    }
}
```

I don't see a clean way to do this. Creating another retrofit request inside the error block or non-successful block would add a lot of code complexity.

Is there an easier way to handle this in Retrofit or OkHttp?

Comment: Try using RxJava or an MVP Architecture to handle asynchronous methods in a better way

Comment: You can increase your server timeout time and check exception for it in on failure method then call again

Comment: If it's just the url that changes and you need this for every request, wouldn't a okhttp interceptor work? You could keep all your retrofit calls untouched.

Comment: @Fred yeah its just the base url that would change. I never used an interceptor before though

Comment: Ok, I'll prepare an example and post it here. Just take it as a "possible solution" and not as "the solution" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have here an option with `OkHttp` interceptors. The idea is that if the request fails you replace the url and execute the request again.

The following is an api client to the [OpenWeather Api](https://openweathermap.org/). If you want to try out the example you'll need to sign up and get an api key. It should be free so I hope this is ok.

I'll post here the full code and then walk you through it.

```
private final static String API_KEY = "<API KEY HERE>";

private static class Weather {
  @SerializedName("id")
  @Expose
  private String id;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

private static final String GOOD_HOST = "api.openweathermap.org";
private static final String BAD_ENDPOINT = "https://api.aaaaaaaaaaa.org";

interface WeatherApiClient {
  @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
  Call<Weather> get(
    @Query("q") String query,
    @Query("appid") String apiKey);
}

private static class ReplicaServerInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) 
                        throws IOException {
     try {
       okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
       return response;
     } catch (IOException e) {

     // Let's build a new request based on the old one
     Request failedRequest = chain.request();

     HttpUrl replicaUrl = failedRequest.url()
        .newBuilder()
        .host(GOOD_HOST)
        .build();

     okhttp3.Request request = failedRequest.newBuilder()
        .url(replicaUrl)
        .build();

     return chain.proceed(request);
   }
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new ReplicaServerInterceptor())
    .build();

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BAD_ENDPOINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();

  WeatherApiClient weatherApiClient = 
            retrofit.create(WeatherApiClient.class);

  weatherApiClient.get("Lisbon,pt", API_KEY)
    .enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
      @Override public void onResponse(
             Call<Weather> call, 
             Response<Weather> response) {
        // This might be null sometimes because 
        // the api is not super reliable, but I didn't
        // add code for this
        System.out.println(response.body().id);
      }

      @Override public void onFailure(
              Call<Weather> call, 
              Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
}
```

To be able to fake a server failure I prepare retrofit to call a non existent url - `BAD_ENDPOINT`. This will trigger the catch clause inside the interceptor.

The interceptor itself is obviously the key thing here. It intercepts every call from retrofit and executes the call. If the call throws an error because the server is down, then it will raise an `IOException`. Here I copy the request being made and change the url.

Changing the url means changing the host:

```
HttpUrl replicaUrl = failedRequest.url()
  .newBuilder()
  .host(GOOD_HOST)
  .build();
```

If you just call `url(<some url>)` in the request builder, everything gets replaced. Query parameters, protocol, etc. This way, we preserve these from the original request.

*(OkHttp offers `newBuilder` methods which copy the data from the current object and let you just edit what you want. Just like kotlin's `copy`. This is why we can simply change the url and be safe that everything else remains the same)*

I then build the new request with the url and execute it:

```
okhttp3.Request request = failedRequest.newBuilder()
  .url(replicaUrl)
  .build();

return chain.proceed(request);
```

Interceptors work on a chain pattern, that's why calling proceed will call the next interceptor on the chain. In this case we just need to actually make the request.

*I didn't bother copying the entire weather resource, so I'm just using the id. I think that's not the main focus of the question*

As I said before, this is meant as a proof of concept. As you noticed I'm `try-catch`ing the execution of the call, but in your case it might be that the call actually succeeds executing, but the http response is not a 2XX. The okhttp response objects have methods that help you checking if the response was successful namely - [isSuccessful()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#isSuccessful--). The idea is the same - Build a new request and carry on if it's not successful.

I didn't bother treating any errors from the replica in this example. They'll just be forwarded to the retrofit client.

As you can see retrofit has no clue where the response is coming from. This might or not be good. Also, the response body needs to be the same from both servers, which I guess it's the case.

Lastly I'm sorry for the awkward `okhttp3.Response` name spacing there. I was using both `Response` from retrofit and okhttp and hence had to avoid the name clash.

**Versions used for this example**: Retrofit 2.3.0 and the okhttp bundled with that